# How do you use Presentation Model with Webforms?

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, presentation-model

I have started using Presentation Model w/ ASP.NET webforms and like the pattern quite a bit. What I am really having an issue with is where to instantiate some of my classes, mostly the presentation model, my business object, and things like the data for drop down lists. So I could use some tips or a complete example of the Presentation Model (I have only find pieces so far).

Answer (score 3):

Video Links -

[Rik Bardof on Design Patterns](http://codebetter.com/blogs/david_laribee/archive/2008/07/16/rik-on-design-patterns.aspx) (including MVP)

[Jean Paul Boohdoo on MVP](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showID=14)

As far as the rest of your architecture goes, I would recommend reading Jeffrey Palermo's blog series on [Onion Architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/).  He has a sample project CodeCampServer that illustrates some good practices.  This is a web app using ASP.NET MVC, but the principles still apply.